# how to configure a smart tv LG as wifi access point

Tags: smart-tv

i don't know if possible but i want to configure smart tv LG to be a wifi access point. for i can connect to this access point by the smartphone.

for exemple i want when I cast on TV by a smartphone I have to connect the latter on the access point offer by the TV in order to avoid any smartphne of to cast on the TV.

it's a mechanism that I follow to put the cast between the TV and the smartphone more secure.

if you have other ideas that allows the cast more secure I will be happy

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple; we need to access the Setting ---> general ----->SoftAp and put it ON

then the access point will activate, and will be displayed password and the SSID of the access point